# Getting jquery to show respective text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quote machine which displays random movie quotes. Now I'm trying to add the name of the movie underneath the quote using jquery but it's not working for some reason. I tried following what others have done on their own quote machine projects or modifying snippets in my own code but I can't seem to figure it out.

Code I've tried:

```
function getQuote() {
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
        var selectedQuote = quotes[randomIndex];

        $('#main-quote').text(selectedQuote.quote);
        var selectedBG = selectedQuote.background;
        console.log(selectedBG);
        $("body").css("background-image", "url('" + selectedBG + "')");

        $('#main-quote').text(selectedQuote.quote);
        var selectedMovie = selectedQuote.movie;
        console.log(selectedMovie);
        $("#what-movie").html("selectedMovie");
    }
```

[Full jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hanyb9da/23/)

Thank you!

Comment: Just remove quotes from `.html("selectedMovie");` Also, you can directly do `.html(selectedQuote.movie)`. No need for another variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrapped the variable `selectedMovie` in quotes, which makes it as text. simply remove the quotes and every thing will fall in place:

```
$("#what-movie").html(selectedMovie);
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wvjnejtn/)**

Comment: Strange, I could have sworn I tried that before. Anyway, simple solution, thanks! :)